# Raspberry pi video streaming image error

Tags: raspbian, archlinux, webcam, streaming-video

I have a problem with video streaming on raspberry pi. When I want to stream the webcam's image trough the network, the image has many errors, like fall apart, other colors and lot of garbage appear on it. I thought that it is my program's error, so I ran the mjpg-streamer, but the errors are the same. Then I removed the raspbian and installed the Arch Linux ARM and the mjpg-streamer, but no changing. I ran out from ideas, and I couldn't find a solution on the Internet.
Peter

Comment: Is your webcam under the supported devices list? http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Webcams

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using gstreamer for streaming. You could start with simple pipeline and try to stream your camera via UDP, that should be simple. By adding queue elements you should avoid errors in incomplete stream.